# Hiding of questions with ignored tags is visible

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, ignored-tags

As I understand, questions with ignored tags are only hidden on the client side.  I guess that's done to lower server's load.  However, the process is quite slow, as in visible on page reloading (even if it actually takes 0.01 seconds).  Can this be improved so that page is initially rendered with hidden questions already hidden somehow?

*(I cannot quite propose anything short of "render the page blank, do the hiding, then show everything", but that's clearly not the way to go.)*

Comment: I've often wondered why questions were fetched, then masked, rather than the reverse.

Comment: @MPelletier: Well, hiding logic needs to be on client side anyway, because hiding is performed dynamically if you add sth. to ignored tags list.  Then if you *remove* sth. from there, relevant questions need to be shown.  I guess the latter (or performance) is the reason why all questions are always loaded.

Comment: @MPelletier - Yes. The question list (newest, hot, featured, etc) are generated once and then heavily cached for performance. It's less expensive, performance wise, to send you that cached page and let your browser remove the hidden parts, rather than generate a custom page just for you.

Comment: I understand. I'm surprised, though, because in a sense the page is always "custom", in that it takes into account the currently active questions, etc. But it makes sense to push final viewing prefs to be determined client side....